# how to extract content of all inside in p tag using php

Tags: php, html, dom

i am trying to extract the contents of all p tags of html inside div class and trying to insert whole stream into one variable array

this are html code example

```
<html>
...
<div class=news-box>

   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
   <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
   <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
   <p>yuoyuouoyuoyuyu oyuiouioyuioyuyiouyoiy youyoiyuioyuioyuyoiuyiuyiyuioyu yuyiu</p>
</div>
...
</html>
```

i want to extract all content in p and trying to insert whole stream into variable for to insert in database, i am using below these php codes

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$html1=file_get_html($url);
$content=array();
foreach($html1->find('div.story-box p') as $e)
{
    $content=$e;
}
echo $content;
?>
```

why it is showing only last line... want to show all contents in p tag after assigning in one variable not `$e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're confused at printing arrays (just use `print_r()` by the way), just concatenate the strings:

```
$contents = '';
foreach($html1->find('div.story-box p') as $e) {
    $contents .= $e;
    // or $contents .= $e . '<br/>';
}

echo $contents;
```

Comment: Thank you @MarioD'Boro i got what i want.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you re-assign `$content` on every iteration. What you want is:

```
foreach($html1->find('div.story-box p') as $e)
{
    $content[] =$e;
}
var_dump($content);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, i am new in php, learing new thing in php. how to echo out to show in browser. i try this echo $content but it show error "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 23
Array". can you please tell me how to echo out in browser after loop.

Comment: you'll notice i used `var_dump($content);`

Comment: use print_r() for array printing

Answer (score 0):

temp1.html

```
   <html>
   <head><title></title></head>
   <body>
    <div  id="text">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
     <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
     <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
    <p>yuoyuouoyuoyuyu oyuiouioyuioyuyiouyoiy youyoiyuioyuioyuyoiuyiuyiyuioyu yuyiu</p>
   </div>
    </body>
    </html
```

temp1.php

```
   <?php
      include("simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php");
      $url = 'http://localhost/temp1.html';
      $html=file_get_html($url);
      $content=array();
      $a="";
     foreach($html->find('div[id=text] p') as $e)
     {
       $a .=$e->plaintext." ";
       // echo $e->plaintext."<br>";
     }
     echo "$a";
   ?>
```

Comment: it suffers the same problem as the OP, `$content` will only be the last element.

Comment: so that means its not retrieving all values from p tag.